# xv6 makefile says undefined reference to __printf_chk

Tags: c, operating-system, xv6

I'm trying to add a user space program in xv6, but when I try to compile it gives error: `"/usr/include/bits/stdio2.h:104: undefined reference to __printf_chk"`. Any help?
My user program:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <sys/user.h>

int 
main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    setbuf(stdout, NULL);
    for (int i = 1; i < argc; i++)
    {
         printf("Print in user space: %s\n", argv[0]);
    }
    exit(0);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: That name (`__printf_chk`) looks like a name that might be implemented in a modern C compiler with a modern C library.  My understanding of XV6 is that it is mainly Unix Version 6, which is anything but modern.  I wonder if you're using a header that is not for the XV6 environment?

Comment: I saw the exact same headers working fine with printf statements in the program.

Comment: Since your program only uses `setbuf()`, `printf()` and `exit()`, it isn't clear how this program that fails differs from the one(s) that work using `printf()`.  You're probably not using the compiler correctly, somehow, but I don't have XV6 on my machines so I can't help much more.

Comment: It isn't clear why you use `exit(0)` making the `return 0;` unreachable.  On the whole, I'd omit the `exit()`, and then you only need the `<stdio.h>` header (you only need that and `<stdlib.h>` if you keep the call to `exit()`).  The other headers probably aren't breaking anything, but it isn't clear they're helping either.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler I think there's some issue in XV6 where `return` from `main` doesn't work but the compiler warns if you don't have the `return` there.

Comment: @JL2210 — judging from the [XV6](https://pdos.csail.mit.edu/6.828/2012/xv6.html) home page, the compiler is GCC 4.5.1, which is more modern than a Unix V6 compiler, but still not quite cutting edge (not now; it may have been when XV6 was first released). As I said, "it isn't clear"; what you describe as mitigating circumstances are not clear to those not intimately familiar with XV6. But that's also why I said "it isn't clear"; that allows for the possibility (apparently, more than just a possibility) that there is a reason. It's more than a little odd that the XV6 environment isn't cleaner.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You've compiled the program with your **host** headers, which are from glibc, but you're trying to link it with the xv6 **target** libraries. That's not going to work. You need to be using a proper cross compiler and taking care not to pollute it with `-I` options that would bring in host headers or `-L` options that would bring in host libraries.

Answer (score 0):

for future reference i will answer dont include normal C header files  you have to use headers provided by the xv6-libraries if u just include normal C headers you will get an error, more specifically delete the C headers and , if you are on RISC-V use #include "user/user.h"